# Raspberry pi server for Blynk, Problem with starting server

Tags: java, raspberry-pi

Hy guys. Sorry for my bad english. I have problem with running server on Raspberry,

**I use this command for starting server:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -jar server-0.41.12-java8.jar - dataFolder home/pi/Blynk
```

**and error message :**

> Exception in thread “main” java.lang.RuntimeException: Error unpacking
> static files. at
> cc.blynk.utils.JarUtil.unpackStaticFiles(JarUtil.java:64) at
> cc.blynk.utils.properties.ServerProperties.(ServerProperties.java:34)
> at
> cc.blynk.utils.properties.ServerProperties.(ServerProperties.java:42)
> at
> cc.blynk.server.launcher.ServerLauncher.main(ServerLauncher.java:55)
> Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
> /home/pi/static/report-email.html at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:90)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.implDelete(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:245)
> at
> java.base/sun.nio.fs.AbstractFileSystemProvider.deleteIfExists(AbstractFileSystemProvider.java:110)
> at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Files.java:1180) at
> cc.blynk.utils.JarUtil.unpackStaticFiles(JarUtil.java:49) … 3 more

Also i have java 11.0.3 but server is on java 8 I think because I don’ make server I just configure server. I try deinstalled java and instal now (8.0) (command with `sudo`) but then write again 11.0.3. (command `java -version`)

Comment: The error report suggests there is a problem with the file at position: `/home/pi/static/report-email.html`, does that file exist, if so what are its permissions, ownership?

Comment: the file exist, group root, 
content overview: anyone, content change: owner, execute: nobody    if I try edit I have error

Comment: try running the java command with `sudo` viz. `sudo java -jar server-0.41.12-java8.jar ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All what you need is start server as a ROOT.
In terminal write `sudo pcmanfm`.
Then open folder in terminal and run server!